# In a procedure(Oracle) showing missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT count(1) FAILED_COUNT FROM RETRY_JEOPARDY
 WHERE TO_CHAR(trans_time - INTERVAL '1' HOUR,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL (:iStep) MINUTE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 AND TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
 AND order_status = 'Active';
```

This is a Query ... where `INTERVAL (:iStep) MINUTE`  in this line showing error

> O/P: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Can u please give me the current solution for this.?How variable interval iStep.

Comment: In your WHERE clause you are converting the date values to character values using `TO_CHAR` and hence you are comparing your date values as character strings instead of date itself. Is this a business requirement? If not, then remove the `TO_CHAR` function and see how the query runs.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? And I totally agree with Rachcha. Converting dates to characters to compare them is totally useless.

Comment: count(1) has no advantage over count(*)

Comment: @Rachcha ... especially when you convert to a DD-MM-YYYY etc format, in which the first of any month will sort lower that the second of any other month.